# Android Webview crashing when loading about:blank with error "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

Tags: android, webview

When loading a url from google drive (this is a pdf that is 27 pages), the webview is crashing when loading "about:blank" with the error "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME". This is also happening when loading a slideshow from google drive, however that one is crashing with a url starting with "chrome-extension". We have looking into many things such as checking for those urls in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function within the website and returning true and removing our custom user agent from the webview, however none of these seemed to work.

With running out of ideas, we decided to see if reloading the webpage on a crash would help and if does most of the time. I have attached some code snippets of the webview we are creating.

```
wv = (WebView)result.findViewById(R.id.map_holder);
try
    {
        wv.setInitialScale(50);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
            {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
            {
                view.loadData(C.ErrorHtml, "text/html", null);
                if(attempts < maxAttempts)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    view.loadUrl(webAddress);
                }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings ("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                view.loadData(C.ErrorHtml, "text/html", null);
                if(attempts < maxAttempts)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    view.loadUrl(webAddress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
            {
                return overrideUrl(url) || super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });

        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            wv.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + wv.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
        }

        wv.loadUrl(webAddress);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.